# Surfaces ruled through a subset of points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

One common definition of a
*[ruled surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface#Developable_surface)*
$S$ is that, through *every* point $p \in S$, there passes a line $L(p)$ that lies
in $S$: $L(p) \subset S$.
My question is:

> **Q0**. Is there any loosening of "through every point $p$" that leads to the conclusion
>   that $S$ is
>   nevertheless still ruled?

(*Added*:) Let us assume $S$ is smooth and $L(p)$ is an infinite line (not a segment).
More specifically:

**Q1**. Is there a surface $S$ through which all but a finite set of
exceptional points, passes a line that lies in $S$? So it is not ruled, but there are   only finite exceptions?

**Q2**. Is there a surface $S$ through which all but a countably infinite set of exceptional points, passes a line that lies in $S$?

**Q3**. If a set of points $P$ is dense on $S$, and through every $p\in P$ 
there passes a line that lies in $S$, does that imply that $S$ ruled?

---

[image: HypParab]

 
<sup>[Image from Univ Arizona Math Teaching Tools](http://math.arizona.edu/~models/Ruled_Surfaces/)</sup>

---

(*Added 14Oct14*).
Here is Robert Bryant's example surface $S$ that shows the answer to
**Q1** is—remarkably—*Yes*.
From $z=xy$ he removes the four red points
$$(1,0,0),\; (−1,0,0),\; (0,−1,0),\; (0,1,0)\;,$$
and then there is no complete line through the five yellow points:
$$(0,0,0),\; (1,1,1),\; (1,−1,−1),\; (−1,1,−1),\; (−1,−1,1)\;,$$
but there is a line through every other point of $S$.

---

[image: BryantRuled]

Comment: What level of regularity are you willing to assume about $S$?  For example, do you assume that $S$ is smooth?  Also, are you interested in pieces of surfaces, i.e., in 'locally ruled' surfaces that may contain only line segments rather than whole lines?

Comment: @RobertBryant: I was primarily interested in smooth $S$ and containing infinite lines. I will so edit. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that if a sequence of lines in $S$ converges to a line $L$, then (assuming $S$ is topologically closed) $L$ must also be in $S$. Doesn't this answer all your questions?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: Yes, that makes sense, and seems to answer all the question variations. Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph:  However, you did not state the assumption that $S$ be topologically closed in your original question, and I assumed that you did not want to.  Without this assumption, the answer to Q1 is yes:  Take $S$ to be the hyperboloid $z-xy=0$ minus the four points $(1,0,0)$, $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, and $(0,1,0)$.  Then, through every point of $S$, there passes a (complete) line in $S$ except for the $5$ points $(0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,-1,0)$, $(-1,1,0)$, and $(-1,-1,0)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks, Robert, indeed I am interested in non-closed surfaces. That is a remarkable example!

Comment: @RobertBryant: I am sure you meant for those last four points to be $(1,1,1), (1,−1,-1), (−1,1,-1), (−1,−1,1)$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  Of course, you are right.  I was too careless (and lazy) in my cut-and-paste editing.  Unfortunately, I can't edit the comment now.  I'm sorry for the error and any confusion it may have caused.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  By the way, I probably should have mentioned that if, instead, one takes $S$ to be the hyperboloid $z-xy=0$ minus the points $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,-1,1)$, then except for the *two* points $(-1,1,-1)$ and $(1,-1,-1)$, every point of $S$ lies on a (complete) line in $S$.  I don't know whether one can construct an example with only one exceptional point.